# Sorting a treeStore in extJs messing up with the application

Tags: sorting, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a treeStore ('planScreenStore') which I'm accessing in the following way :

```
        updateStore : function() {

                    rootNodeID = globals.GlobalModel.planList.scope._id;
                    var planScreenStoreRootNode = this.planScreenStore.getRootNode();

                    if (!(planScreenStoreRootNode === undefined)) {
                        planScreenStoreRootNode.removeAll();
                    }
                    if (globals.GlobalModel.planList.children.length > 0) {
                        planScreenStoreRootNode.appendChild(
                                globals.GlobalModel.planList.children);
                        globals.GlobalModel.planList.children = planScreenStoreRootNode;
                        globals.GlobalModel.planListForCreateNewPlan = planScreenStoreRootNode;
                    }
```

I have to sort the treeStore on the basis of its field 'text'.
I have been able to do so in the following two ways:

```
     updateStore : function() {
                    debugger;
                    rootNodeID = globals.GlobalModel.planList.scope._id;
                    var planScreenStoreRootNode = this.planScreenStore.getRootNode();

                    if (!(planScreenStoreRootNode === undefined)) {
                        planScreenStoreRootNode.removeAll();
                    }
                    if (globals.GlobalModel.planList.children.length > 0) {
                        planScreenStoreRootNode.appendChild(
                                globals.GlobalModel.planList.children);
                        globals.GlobalModel.planList.children = planScreenStoreRootNode;
                        globals.GlobalModel.planListForCreateNewPlan = planScreenStoreRootNode;
                    }
                        this.planScreenStore.sort('text','ASC');
```

and the other one:

```
     updateStore : function() {
                    debugger;
                    rootNodeID = globals.GlobalModel.planList.scope._id;
                    var planScreenStoreRootNode = this.planScreenStore.getRootNode();

                    if (!(planScreenStoreRootNode === undefined)) {
                        planScreenStoreRootNode.removeAll();
                    }
                    if (globals.GlobalModel.planList.children.length > 0) {
                        planScreenStoreRootNode.appendChild(
                                globals.GlobalModel.planList.children);
                        globals.GlobalModel.planList.children = planScreenStoreRootNode;
                        globals.GlobalModel.planListForCreateNewPlan = planScreenStoreRootNode;
                    }


                    planScreenStoreRootNode.sort(function(n1, n2) {
                        debugger ;
                        var v1 = n1.data['text'].toUpperCase();
                        var v2 = n2.data['text'].toUpperCase();

                        if (v1 < v2)
                            return -1;
                        else if (v1 > v2)
                            return 1;
                        return 0;
                    });
```

I get the desired result with both the methods but somehow in both the cases, my application crashes after the sorting is performed while it works entirely fine without either of the sorting applied. Is it something related to how I'm accessing the NodeInterface (planScreenRootNode). How can i resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes" does it give an error message? Or just freeze up your browser?

Comment: @FoxMulder900 It freezes up the browser and I'm unable to navigate to any further screens